# Ошибка в сравнении значений при использовании BigDecimal и compareTo() в Java

Tags: java, spring, junit, java-8, bigdecimal

Уважаемые разработчики!

Стоит задача сравнить данные и сделать подсчеты. К сожалению после написания тестов выяснилось что метод работает не верно, пытался разобраться , считаю что ошибка в неправильном сравнении BigDecimal. Прошу ПОМОЧЬ НАЙТИ ОШИБКУ.

Заранее спасибо!

Задача :

PREMIUM_THEFT = SUM_INSURED_THEFT * COEFFICIENT_THEFT SUM_INSURED_THEFT - total sum insured of all
policy's sub-objects with type "Theft" COEFFICIENT_THEFT - by default 0.11 but if SUM_INSURED_THEFT equal or greater than 15 then 0.05

( Где, SUM_INSURED_THEFT вводит сам пользователь а COEFFICIENT_THEFT расчитываеться в зависимости от числа которое ввели)

Код метода который реализует данную задачу :

```
    @Override
    public BigDecimal apply() {
        if (value.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0) {
            throw new IncorrectlyEnteredDataException("Value cannot be negative!");
        } else if (value.compareTo(PREMIUM_DEFAULT_VALUE) >= 0) {
            setCoefficientTheft(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.05));
        } else if (value.compareTo(PREMIUM_DEFAULT_VALUE) < 0) {
            setCoefficientTheft(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.11));
        }
        return value.multiply(getCoefficientTheft());
    }
```

Тесты :

```
@Test
    public void shouldCalculatePremiumTheftWithDefaultValue() {
        RiskTypeTheft riskTypeTheft = new RiskTypeTheft(BigDecimal.valueOf(10));
        BigDecimal actual = riskTypeTheft.apply();
        assertEquals(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.5), actual);
    }

    //set_coefficient need to be 0.11 , actual = 20 * 0.11 = 2.2
    @Test
    public void shouldCalculatePremiumFireWithBiggerValue() {
        RiskTypeTheft riskTypeTheft = new RiskTypeTheft(BigDecimal.valueOf(20));
        BigDecimal actual = riskTypeTheft.apply();
        assertEquals(BigDecimal.valueOf(2.2), actual);
    }
```

Также ниже прикладываю скриншоты самого метода и класса + как отработали сами тесты :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле у вас несколько проблем. Действительно, сравнение выполняется неправильно. Помимо этого метод apply() излишне сложно реализован. И последнее - у вас проблема с тестами. Значения с плавающей точкой так сравнивать нельзя, нужно задавать дельту (т.е. допустимую погрешность), ведь это неточные значения.

```
    public BigDecimal apply() {
        if (value.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0) 
            throw new IncorrectlyEnteredDataException("Value cannot be negative!");
        return value.compareTo(PREMIUM_DEFAULT_VALUE) < 0 ? 
                BigDecimal.valueOf(0.5) : value.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.11));
    }



import java.math.BigDecimal;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class RiskTypeTheftTest {

    private final double delta = 0.1;

    @Test
    public void shouldCalculatePremiumTheftWithDefaultValue() {
        RiskTypeTheft riskTypeTheft = new RiskTypeTheft(BigDecimal.valueOf(10));
        double actual = riskTypeTheft.apply().doubleValue();
        assertEquals(0.5, actual, delta);
    }

    //set_coefficient need to be 0.11 , actual = 20 * 0.11 = 2.2
    @Test
    public void shouldCalculatePremiumFireWithBiggerValue() {
        RiskTypeTheft riskTypeTheft = new RiskTypeTheft(BigDecimal.valueOf(20));
        double actual = riskTypeTheft.apply().doubleValue();
        assertEquals(2.2, actual, delta);
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, особенно за тесты, дельта в тестах для меня что то новое. Обязательно буду пользоваться этим.

Answer (score 0):

поменяйте

```
public BigDecimal apply() {
        if (value.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0) {
            throw new IncorrectlyEnteredDataException("Value cannot be negative!");
        } else if (value.compareTo(PREMIUM_DEFAULT_VALUE) >= 0) {
            setCoefficientTheft(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.11));
        } else if (value.compareTo(PREMIUM_DEFAULT_VALUE) < 0) {
            setCoefficientTheft(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.05));
        }
        return value.multiply(getCoefficientTheft());
    }
```

и все тесты пройдут

Comment: Спасибо большое!